# Creating new resource in Terraform using vCloud Director provider

Tags: terraform, vcloud-director-rest-api

I created a pair vm+vapp using the following Terraform code:

```
resource "vcd_vapp" demo_vapp {
  name = "demo"
  power_on = true
}

resource "vcd_vapp_vm" demo {
  vapp_name     = "${vcd_vapp.demo_vapp.name}"
  name          = "demo"
  catalog_name  = "${var.template_catalog}"
  template_name = "${var.clone_source}"
  memory        = "${var.mem_size}"
  cpus          = "${var.cpu_count}"
  network {
    type               = "org"
    name               = "${var.network_name}"
    ip                 = ""
    ip_allocation_mode = "POOL"
    is_primary         = true
  }
  depends_on = ["vcd_vapp.demo_vapp"]
}
```

In vcloud panel from the vApp menu level, I created a template and put in custom catalog. Then I wanted to make more clones using this very template as a source. Unfortunately I ended up with:

```
vcd_vapp.demo_vapp: Creating..
vcd_vapp.demo_vapp: Creation complete after 5s [id=demo]
vcd_vapp_vm.demo: Creating...
Error: merror adding VM: &errors.errorString{s:"vApp Template shape is not ok (status: 3)"}

  on 02_template.tf line 19, in resource "vcd_vapp_vm" "demo":
  19: resource "vcd_vapp_vm" demo
```

From what I found [here](https://github.com/vmware/go-vcloud-director/blob/master/govcd/vapp.go) and [here](https://vdc-repo.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/94b8bd8d-74ff-4fe3-b7a4-41ae31516ed7/1b42f3b5-8b31-4279-8b3f-547f6c7c5aa8/doc/GUID-843BE3AD-5EF6-4442-B864-BCAE44A51867.html) code 3 is an error returned when object is suspended and indeed, the template (as others) is in suspended state. Which is nonsense, what other state should be the template in? Not in 'running' I recon - it's just a template! Does anybody have an idea how to do such an operation? TF is 0.12.8 vcd plugin 2.4

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error. The issue is that the template was created from a powered-on VM.

My solution was to re-create the template using a powered-off VM.